# webpack Hot Middleware updates across all tabs instances when using multiple tabs / browsers

Tags: reactjs, webpack, browser-sync, webpack-hmr, webpack-hot-middleware

I've bumped into an issue with `webpack-hot-middleware`, when i open multiple instances of browsers or tabs (chrome and FF) i get refreshes or updates on all of them on each visual action being triggered.
For example, scrolling on 1 tab triggers a scroll on another tab.
Anyone came across this behavior?
this my config of webpack:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import path from 'path';

export default {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  entry: [
    // must be first entry to properly set public path
    './src/webpack-public-path',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js') // Defining path seems necessary for this to work consistently on Windows machines.
  ],
  target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'), // Tells React to build in either dev or prod modes. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html (See bottom)
      __DEV__: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({     // Create HTML file that includes references to bundled CSS and JS.
      template: 'src/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      inject: true
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: false,
      debug: true,
      noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
      options: {
        sassLoader: {
          includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scss')]
        },
        context: '/',
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
      {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
      {test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']}
    ]
  }
};
```

i have no special configs of the plugin beside passing the webconfig of course:

```
// This file configures the development web server
// which supports hot reloading and synchronized testing.

// Require Browsersync along with webpack and middleware for it
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
// Required for react-router browserHistory
// see https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/204#issuecomment-102623643
import historyApiFallback from 'connect-history-api-fallback';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';

const bundler = webpack(config);

// Run Browsersync and use middleware for Hot Module Replacement
browserSync({
  port: 3000,
  ui: {
    port: 3001
  },
  server: {
    baseDir: 'src',

    middleware: [
      historyApiFallback(),

      webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
        // Dev middleware can't access config, so we provide publicPath
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath,

        // These settings suppress noisy webpack output so only errors are displayed to the console.
        noInfo: false,
        quiet: false,
        stats: {
          assets: false,
          colors: true,
          version: false,
          hash: false,
          timings: false,
          chunks: false,
          chunkModules: false
        },

        // for other settings see
        // http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-middleware.html
      }),

      // bundler should be the same as above
      webpackHotMiddleware(bundler)
    ]
  },

  // no need to watch '*.js' here, webpack will take care of it for us,
  // including full page reloads if HMR won't work
  files: [
    'src/*.html'
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the reason for this behavior and its not related to `webpack-hot-middleware` at all.
Actually what cause this is the `browserSync` plugin.
After some reading of their docs, i found out that 
by default it has a [ghostMode](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-ghostMode) option set to true.

> Clicks, Scrolls & Form inputs on any device will be mirrored to all others.

You can disable it by setting it to false.
`ghostMode: false`.

Hope it can help other people.